# Remove a bad commit from branch in mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch, commit

I've got the following problem:

I have 2 named branches which are 2 completely versions of the product (e.g A and B) than at some moment I was needed to introduce changes from A to B so I started the following command:

```
hg merge A
```

after that commit and push ... and instead of 2 branches I've got 1 that was unexpected for me since I wanted just update B with changes in A. Somehow I managed to get again 2 branches and now I want to delete last commit in branch B and cant find the best way (I'd say any way) to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Where did you push it? Do you have control over who else (if anyone) has a clone with that changeset in it?

Comment: I pushed it to a remote repo but nobody except me uses this branch. It's the last commit for the branch B but there are lot of commits in the branch A.

Comment: Ok, but where did you push it? Is it a place like bitbucket or whatnot? If it is, you probably can't get rid of it on the server, and thus I would just leave it. If you need to undo the changes in the changeset, you can do a backout of that changeset to undo its changes. It'll still be in the history, but you've negated the changes it introduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue commiting to the branch that you want stil alive. There is a command to explicitely kill a branch but if you don't use it, all branches are still alive in parallel. If you don't see them it's only because the tool to see them don't show them all if they are not different, but they're still present. Just continue to work with those branches and it will be fine.

Now to remove a changeset, you "can't" as in really removing it, but you can commit an exact inverse of that specific changeset. The command to do this is `backout`.

Comment: Thanks I tried backout but it seems I have should used it wrong